# Converting SQL query with count() and min() to HQL

Tags: sql, hql

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT tab2.Tavolo, MIN(mycount) as num_posti_min  
FROM (
        SELECT tab1.Tavolo, COUNT(tab1.Tavolo) as mycount
        FROM posto as tab1
        WHERE tab1.disponibilita = true  
        GROUP BY tab1.Tavolo
        HAVING COUNT(tab1.Tavolo) >= 1
    ) as tab2;
```

How can I convert it in HQL?
How can I then read its result?

Comment: Your outer query has a column in the `SELECT` (`Tavolo`) that is not being aggregated.  This is improper SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Hibernate properties instead of writing `HQL` like this

```
session.createSQLQuery(String sqlQuery)
```

[see an example here](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql.shtml)

Comment: how do I get the min result from "group by"? @Sabyasachi